# Observing relationship between different variables of a dataframe using pairplot and correlation method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I have taken the Pima diabetes data from Kaggle for manipulating and creating the data. However, I wanted to plot the relationship between two different variable of the dataframe that I have imported the pima data to. I am able to achieve it using the below query.

```
sns.pairplot(pima_data)
```

The data information is as below:

```
 Pregnancies  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin   BMI  \
0            6      148             72             35        0  33.6   
1            1       85             66             29        0  26.6   
2            8      183             64              0        0  23.3   
3            1       89             66             23       94  28.1   
4            0      137             40             35      168  43.1   

   DiabetesPedigreeFunction  Age  Outcome  
0                     0.627   50        1  
1                     0.351   31        0  
2                     0.672   32        1  
3                     0.167   21        0  
4                     2.288   33        1
```

Below is the graph image:

[image: pair plot information for Pima diabetes]

However, I am not able to figure out how can I plot the relationship between two different variables using **correlation** method and **pairplot** simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to plot the linear regression on top of each scatter plot?

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g = g.map_offdiag(sns.regplot)
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to find the correlation between two variable and then plot it using pair plot. I am not able to find any solution on how to achieve it!!!

Comment: I am showing the correlation. Please provide more explainations about what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to know the r, the r^2? Do you want to plot the scatter plot, or just a correlation matrix?

Comment: I want to use pair plot and correlation method to observe the relationship between different variables. I can use heatmap on the same and then pairplot to achieve the above. Can I use both simultaneously to achieve it